# consulta select numa base de dados

Tags: postgresql

boas é o seguinte estou a mexer aqui com uns dados, tenho uma tabela com dados dos censos.

Tabelas

Primeira tabela onde tem os dados .

Campos residencia_nut3, trabalho_nut3
valores 112, 180
valores 149,146

tabela nut3
campos id,descricao
valores 112 porto
valores 149 coimba
valores 180 lisboa
valores 146 santarem

tabela nut2
campos id,descricao
valores 11 norte
14 centro
18 sul

agora eu  consigo fazer fluxo de dados com os nut3 mas com a nut 2 nao sei como fazer . associar nut 3 a nut 2.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor sua pergunta, definindo melhor as tabelas e seus campos e a relação de tabela/campo. Poderia colocar o código de criação delas? Assim fica mais fácil te ajudar :)

Comment: ora ve ja esta mais claro.

Comment: pensei em partir a nut 3 e comparar com os 2 primeiros numeros...assim ja acho a nut2 da nut3 correspondente